# Porting program, curious if int16_t & __int16 are 'the same'

Tags: c++, types

So i am porting one of my programs to a new gaming console. The problem is that the SDK used to compile my c++ application doesn't support `__int16`, BUT it does have `int16_t`.
Would it be 'safe' to use `int16_t` in replace of `__int16`?
Also, if im not mistaken could i just use `unsigned short int` for a 16 bit `integer` rather than using `int16_t` or `__int16`?

Comment: What development environment are you coming from? What development environment are you migrating to? I suspect the answer will depend on that.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that `int16_t` is standard. It's defined in `<cstdint>` or `<stdint.h>`. It was added to the C standard in 1999, and adopted by the C++ standard later (C++11?). Also, the name `__int16` is reserved; you shouldn't define anything with that name in your own code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They will be the same.

People used to define their own fixed width types before the standard ones came out. Just use a typedef - that's what they are for.

Answer (score 1):

`int16_t` and `__int16` should both be signed 16-bit integers. Substituting one for the other should be fine. `unsigned short int` is completely different. It is unsigned rather than signed and it isn't guaranteed to be 16 bits. It could end up being a different size.